# How do I echo a a base64 string as an image to the browser using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, base64

I've got a database with base64 strings of images. I've now built an API call to display these images by their uuid (`example.com/image/5e7edbe0-a765-4863-9d75-9f89ccc532e0`). I get the value from the database, decode it from base64 to binary, and then echo it to the browser as follows:

```
$document = DocumentModel::getFromDatabase($uuid);
$type = $document->getType(); // image/png

$valueBase64 = $document->getValue(); // data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAAAAABX3VL4AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3gYSDCUgSze0AAAAAA5JREFUCNdjrGJgYmAAAAJ0AH4SDHVIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
$value = base64_decode($valueBase64);

header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
echo $value;
```

Unfortunately, I get one of these broken images icons saying that the image can't load. If I take the raw base64 value from the database and try to render it in the browser using the Javascript console like below it indeed shows the image (a 2x2 pixel grey image).

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAIAAAACCAAAAABX3VL4AAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAAAB3RJTUUH3gYSDCUgSze0AAAAAA5JREFUCNdjrGJgYmAAAAJ0AH4SDHVIAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

So I really don't understand why echo'ing the binary value like I do doesn't work. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? All tips are welcome!

Comment: If `$valueBase64` *really* contains `data:image/png;base64,` then you'll need to strip that from the string as `base64_decode()` will not recognize such input (it takes *pure* Base64 only).

Comment: in other words, you can't decode a data uri. a data uri contains base64 information, but it also has that "header" component which is **NOT** base64.

Comment: @LinusKleen - Awesome! That was indeed the solution! That means I have to change things on the insert side as well. That is built with Javascript. Would you possibly have any idea how I can strip that part away using Javascript?

Comment: Nevermind, already got it! @LinusKleen - If you put up your comment as an answer I can tick it as the correct answer.. :) Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

The string in `$valueBase64` contains a [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme), which is unacceptable for PHP's [`base64_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function, since it only accepts *pure* base64 encoded data.

In order for your program to work, you'll have to strip the header (the `data:image/png;base64,` part - including the comma) from the input data.

Comment: Hello, revenge downvoter. I have [more answers to downvote](http://stackoverflow.com/users/255756/linus-kleen?tab=answers) for you.